# Only return first 20 results of JSON data passed by $.ajax?

Tags: json, jquery, for-loop

I have the following simple jquery snippet

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
             url:"myjson.json",
             dataType: 'json',
             success:function(json){
                 $.each(json, function() {
                    alert("test");
                });
             },
             error:function(){
             },
        });
    });
```

The result can return 1000's of results - i only want the first 20 for example. How would i best do this?

Comment: The first choice should be: make your server-side handler accept a parameter that lets the client specify how many results should be returned. Do you have control over the server code?

Comment: I don't think you can do an AJAX request and just receive the first 20 entries (it has to fetch the whole response), can't you do that server-side like `myjson.json?from=0&to=20`?

Comment: You'd be better off doing it server-side. What is the point of the overhead of returning 1000+ results if you only need the first 20 ones...

Comment: Yeah, do that in on the server side. It does not make sense to let the server fetch all items and send them to the client if you are only interested in a handful of them.

Comment: Yes, my first thought - but i dont have access to the server-side code. So only option is to do it client side i am afraid. Cant i limit the 4.each somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The callback for `.each()` has an argument `index` which is the index in the original collection. You break out of the iteration by returning false from the callback.

So you would do something like:

```
$.each(json, function(index) {
    if(index < 20)
      alert("test");
    else
       return false;
});
```

As others has commented it is better to do this server side, but maybe you have no access to server side code?

Comment: Side note: If index has 1000 items, then they were still sent in the http response.

Answer (score 3):

In case you really want to (or have to) do this client side you can break an `$.each` loop by returning `false` at a certain iteration.

See **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/92pDy/)** for a basic example of how to do this.

In your case that would lead to:

```
success:function(json){
                 $.each(json, function(index) {
                    alert("test");
                    if (index === 19){return false}
                });
             }
```

Also see **[the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)**:

> We can break the $.each() loop at a particular iteration by making the
>   callback function return false. Returning non-false is the same as a
>   continue statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next
>   iteration.